# KENDO-ANGULAR Export grid and chart in single pdf

Tags: angular, charts, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I am working with the Kendo-angular. Need to export the grid and chart in single pdf. I found one example http://dojo.telerik.com/@tsvetomir/ubOhe it is with the jquery . How I can achive the same thing with Kendo-Angular.

Any suggetion will be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [PDFExport component](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/pdfexport/) and add all desired components (like Chart, Grid, etc.) inside, e.g.:

```
<kendo-pdf-export #pdf1 paperSize="A4" margin="1cm">
<kendo-chart [categoryAxis]="{ categories: categories }">
        <kendo-chart-title text="Gross domestic product growth /GDP annual %/"></kendo-chart-title>
        <kendo-chart-legend position="bottom" orientation="horizontal"></kendo-chart-legend>
        <kendo-chart-tooltip format="{0}%"></kendo-chart-tooltip>
        <kendo-chart-series>
            <kendo-chart-series-item *ngFor="let item of series"
                type="line" style="smooth" [data]="item.data" [name]="item.name">
            </kendo-chart-series-item>
        </kendo-chart-series>
    </kendo-chart>
    <my-invoice [data]="data"></my-invoice>
 </kendo-pdf-export>
```

[EXAMPLE](https://plnkr.co/edit/JtcOIxgDSVcENpsLNHUr?p=preview)